# Abrir enlace con extensión htm

Tags: html, html5, html-select

Estoy intentando abrir una pagina para realizar unos ejercicios online pero ningun navegador me la muetra. La pagina en concreto es **http://recursos.cnice.mec.es/biosfera/alumno/4ESO/evolucion/actividad4.htm**

Lo he intentado con Google Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explore, MIcrosoft Edge, Opera
El mensaje que me tiran los navegadores es  **"WARNING: Your browser version cannot show this page."**. Tambien intente descargar el enlace a un bloc de notas para abrirlo nuevamente con alguno de los navegadores que describi arriba. Otra prueba que realice es mediante paginas online que convierten htm a html pero no obtuve resultado alguno, me tiran el mismo mensaje

Alguna idea ??

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con ssl o tls o mejor dicho intenta con `https://` en lugar de `http://`

Comment: Nada, tampoco responde con https. Posiblemente el sitio este caído, lo raro es que si veo el código **htm** con el editor de texto, puedo ver el contenido de la pagina, pero no consigo visualizarla. Alguna otra idea, gracias

Comment: Ya revise su código y es que ese código solo es compatible con netscape y internet explorer

Comment: Pero que versión de Internet Explorer ??. Porque lo estoy abriendo con **IE versión 11.778.18362.0** en Windows10 y me lanza el mismo error

Comment: El código dice version 4 y 5

Comment: Conseguí que me funcionase con IEv8. Muchas gracias a todos !!!